# Estimate Z value from 2D image after converting to grayscale

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, image-processing

I am working in a project to estimate road profile (Elevation) from a 2D images captured with the same height from road surface and same orientation (angle), the following code is my first try :

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import imread
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

imageFile = 'D:\Books\Pav Man\PICS\pic (17) - Copy.png'


mat = imread(imageFile,0)

mat = mat[:,:,0] # get the first channel

#mat = mat - np.full_like(mat , mat.mean()) #Use this to get negative value
rows, cols = mat.shape

xv, yv = np.meshgrid(range(cols), range(rows)[::-1])

blurred = ndimage.gaussian_filter(mat, sigma=(5, 5), order=0)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(221)
ax.imshow(mat, cmap='gray')
ax = fig.add_subplot(222, projection='3d')
ax.elev= 75
ax.plot_surface(xv, yv, mat)
ax = fig.add_subplot(223)
ax.imshow(blurred, cmap='gray')
ax = fig.add_subplot(224, projection='3d')
ax.elev= 75
ax.plot_surface(xv, yv, blurred)
plt.show()


)
```

from this code, I can show an image in grayscale then I can get color value (0-255) for each pixel in the image. 
consider I have the average Z elevation of a number of a pixel with color value, is it correct to estimate Z (elevation) by calibration, by example:
pixel (x=20,y=100) have color value 150 and the elevation in the real world in the road is 20 cm, then I consider each pixel in this image with color value 150 should have 20 cm elevation in the real world.

and if this estimation correct, can I applied this for different images with the same height from the surface and the same orientation?

Comment: This question does not sound like a question for stackoverflow. I'd guess that the surface properties of the road can disrupt this mapping and generalizing to other images would require the lighting, camera settings and probably other environment properties to be constant.

Comment: Thank you for your comment,if i control light and camera settings , is it correct to estimate Z as the method mentioned above.

Comment: As I said, that would assume the same surface properties of the road at all pixels, which sounds unrealistic to me.

Comment: Why I should assume "same surface properties for all road" ? , and if there is another method can I use it?

Comment: As I pointed out in the first comment, this question does not seem to belong here. A road does not have a single color but at least some kind of pattern, it can be wet, inclined at an angle and so on...

Comment: ok, thank you very much